# Compute derivative by quotient rule: Why $2x-8t$ in the argument of exponentials?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am wondering about the following:

[image]

I hope it is not too stupid to ask whether there is  a mistake, because I get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{2e^{8t-2x}}{1+e^{8t-2x}}\right)=-\frac{4e^{8t-2x}}{(1+e^{8t-2x})^2}
$$
and thus
$$
u(x,t)=-\frac{8e^{8t-2x}}{(1+e^{8t-2x})^2}
$$

I do not see why the arguments of the exponentials should be $2x-8t$ instead of $8t-2x$.

Comment: could just be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Typo. Let $f=8t-2x$.

$$u(x,t)/4 = \frac{(1+e^f)(-2e^f)-e^f(-2e^f)}{(1+e^f)^2} = \frac{-2e^f}{(1+e^f)^2} \neq \frac{-2e^{-f}}{(1+e^{-f})^2} $$